# cursor index exception in android SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to implement a simple DB example using `SQLITE`. Here is my code

```
package com.example.dbex;

import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.sql.SQLPermission;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="contactsmanager";
    public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS="contacts";
    public static final String KEY_ID="id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="name";
    public static final String KEY_NUMBER="number";
    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_CONTACTS+"("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+KEY_NAME+" TEXT,"+KEY_NUMBER+" TEXT"+")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_CONTACTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addContact(Contacts contacts)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contacts.getname());
        values.put(KEY_NUMBER, contacts.getnumber());
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS,null,values);
        db.close();
    }

    public Contacts getContact(int id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c=db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_NUMBER},KEY_ID+" =?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if(c!=null)
        {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        Contacts contacts=new Contacts(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)),c.getString(1),c.getString(2));
        return contacts;
    }

    public void deleteContact(Contacts contacts)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID+" =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contacts.getID())});
        db.close();
    }


}
```

`

I'm getting a **cursor out of bounds exception** on the line

```
Contacts contacts=new Contacts(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)),c.getString(1),c.getString(2));
```

Where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Your cursor is probably empty.

It can be not null but still have no results (0 rows returned). You can make sure you access it only if it has results by changing your logic to:

```
Contact contacts = null;
if (c!=null && c.moveToFirst()) {
    contacts = new Contacts(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)),c.getString(1),c.getString(2));
}
return contacts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cursor out of bound exception generally comes when you try to access cursor position when there is not that many rows inside cursor .Print log about number of rows cursor have and if it is not 0 than only try to access further rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
    Contacts getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_NUMBER }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    Contacts contacts; 
    if (cursor != null)
    {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    contacts = new Contacts(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    }
    return contacts

}
```